# Error 95 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FindIndex'

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am converting my existing Windows Phone 8 app to WP 7.1. However I've encountered an error

```
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FindIndex'
```

in this line. What am I missing?

```
index = Array.FindIndex(AnswerLevelArr, s => s.Contains(CurrentFileName));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.FindIndex Method (T[], Predicate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/03y7c6xy%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is not supported in Windows Phone 7.1.

> Version Information
>
> Windows Phone OS
>   Supported in: 8.0

Instead, you may use `Linq` (make sure that you add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file):

```
index = AnswerLevelArr
    .Select((i, position) => new { Item = i, IndexOf = position })
    .First(s => s.Item.Contains(CurrentFileName)).IndexOf;
```

or:

```
int index=0;
var result = AnswerLevelArr.SkipWhile((s, ind) =>
{
    if (!s.Contains(CurrentFileName))
    {
        index++;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}).First();
```

Comment: Ah.. I see. Do you have any suggestion like a quick workaround for this?

Comment: I tried the first one but it says `System.Array does not contain a definition for Select...` The second one does not contain a definition for SkipWhile. Can a simple statement like this work?  `index = Array.IndexOf(AnswerLevelArr, CurrentFileName);`

Comment: You have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

according to msdn

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(
    T[] array,
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy.aspx

you need to include the type?

EDIT: `index = Array.FindIndex<T>(AnswerLevelArr, s => s.Contains(CurrentFileName));`

EDIT2: Left above up for history but is wrong after further inspection...

If you wanted a find index similar to your method you could provide an override

```
int FindIndex(string s)
{
    int size = this.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if(this[i] = s)
        return i;
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. FindIndex is not listed in the intellisense for WP 7.1 Visual Studio 2012 but it's there when creating WP 8 app.

Comment: It is indeed not supported for Windows Phone 7 or 7.1 as the other two answers already say.

Comment: Ah I appologise, not long woke up ^.^, if this wasn't for wp7 then would be valid..

Comment: I've attached a sketchy example of such a function if you wanted to create one yourself

Comment: Why can a statement like this `index = Array.IndexOf(AnswerLevelArr, CurrentFileName)` work?

Answer (score 1):

From [`Array.FindIndex<T> Method (T[], Predicate<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/03y7c6xy%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
Version Information
Windows Phone OS
Supported in: 8.0
```

It is looks like this method not supported in `Windows Phone 7.1`